# Check data in a file JSON?

Tags: c#, json

how can I check data in a JSON File in C#? I would like my program to check if the data is present in the JSON file or not with an if, how should I do? For example in this file JSON [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkTXz.png) How am I supposed to do the check?  (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Check for what?

Comment: take it as a string is you can't make a class object

Comment: To see if the data type is present in the file or not

Comment: your data is organized as a dictionary, so read it, convert the JSON to dictionary<string, string>  and lookup the value in the dictionary like in this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your JSON as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for textual data, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate the JSON against schema like this.

```
string schemaJson = @"{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties':
  {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'hobbies': {
      'type': 'array',
      'items': {'type':'string'}
    }
  }
}";

JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'James',
  'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
}");

bool valid = person.IsValid(schema);
```

Reference: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm